# is php sha1 encoding a base32 or base64 hash?

Tags: php, encoding

I wonder to know if sha1 or md5 generating a string in base32 or base64 ?

Because i need to multiply passwords in database to specific dates when temporary generated passwords expires,

or other techniques to save them on session cookies

Comment: save password on cookies. Worst. Idea. Ever.

Comment: yes but i want to multiply it with some random numbers

Comment: I'd love to know what for exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. By default the value is returned in HEX notation (16 character alphabet). That's not related to any base* encoding at all.

Comment: Yes, but base 16 is a straight forward alternative notation of binary. base64 OTOH is an encoding with more complex rules.

Comment: Well, that's just by human notation. Complex or not, the bases are the cited.

Comment: so if i convert it to base 10 it will a number wholly in numbers? and would help to generate some more complex temporary passwords

Comment: @Barazesh Yes, indeed.